# Copy Artifacts from Mutliple pipelines and zip them Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using CopyArtifact plugin in master pipeline to copy files from child pipelines using below code. Is there a to zip directory in master pipeline after copying them into workspace. Below is my code want to zip test directory in workspace.

```
 step([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
     projectName: "child-pipelines/${externalJob}",
     filter: "test/**/*",
     target: "$WORKSPACE"
  ])
```

Comment: "Is there a to zip directory in master pipeline after copying them into workspace" makes no sense to me.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)